# Using phonegap on android to hit a server ( that uses dot net) and display the data

Tags: android, jquery, .net, cordova

I am new to app development using phone gap and I dont know much about server side coding either. I more into making games, so if my question is basic or the answer is well known, then please bear with me. 
I already have a web app ready that uses aspx pages to get data from the server and display it.Using phonegap on iOS, it is possible to display this data. But, when I use the same thing in android, it does not work. Any help is appreciated. My index.html, that Im using to make a jQuery to fetch the page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello Cordova</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $("body").load('http://203.115.112.5/f1/xhtml/daywiselk.aspx?comicid=0');
                </script>
</body>
```

Again, I don't have knowledge about jQuery but I got this from another question on stack overflow, but this works on iOS. But when I try to load the same page in android, nothing is displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Hi check your permissions in manifest fie keep your js file in a separate folder and give that path. it will load your url.